# How to use setval into a function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, sequence

I created a trigger function to set the value of a sequence in a remote database table, using `dblink` and `setval`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function () RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
  ...

BEGIN
    PERFORM dblink('dbname=remote_db user=user3 password=PW12345',  
    'SELECT setval(''my_sequence'',123);')
    ;
    
    RETURN NULL;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
SECURITY DEFINER
;
```

However, I get the following error message when the function is executed:

```
ERROR:  function returning record called in context that cannot accept type record
```

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried `PERFORM setval(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For functions returning `record` or `SETOF record`, the query needs to define the structure of the record. Look at the documentation of `dblink()`!

In your case, you could use

```
PERFORM FROM dblink(
                'dbname=remote_db user=user3 password=PW12345',  
                'SELECT setval(''my_sequence'',123);'
             ) AS setval(newval bigint);
```